# Every element in $\operatorname{Sym}(n)$ can be written as a product of transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra

why is the following true?:

Let $\gamma=(a_1,\ldots,a_k)=(a_1,a_k)(a_1,a_{k-1})(a_1,a_{k-2})(a_1,a_3)(a_1,a_2)$

I am trying it with an easier example
$\gamma=(a_1,\ldots,a_5)=(a_1,a_5)(a_1,a_4)(a_1,a_3)(a_1,a_2)$

In the previous case, $a_1$ goes to $a_2$ but $a_2$ doesn't go anywhere in the second cycle, so does it send $a_1$ or $a_2$?

Comment: The first cycle sends $a_2$ to $a_1$.

Comment: Don't confuse the overall cycle with the component transpositions. In both of your examples $a_2$ is sent to $a_1$ by the first transposition which is then sent to $a_2$ in the second, with the net result that $a_2$ is sent to $a_3$ in the overall cycle.

Comment: I am still confused. I don't get it.

Comment: I think I know got your point, but it contradicts everything I know so far. Are we  transposing cycles or what are we doing?

Comment: by what you are saying $a_1$ to $a_2$  then $a_2$ to $a_1$, but $a_1$ go to $ a_3$, and then it stops because $a_3$ doesn't appear in the remaining cycles, but I don't get what's the point of that algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you have this order of elements: $a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5$.

Now, to avoid what seems to be your confusion, denote the permutation $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$ by $(1,2,3,4,5)$, so after applying that to $a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5$ you get
$$(1,2,3,4,5)[a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5]= a_5a_1a_2a_3a_4 $$

For the other side we start with
$$(1,2)[a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5]= a_2a_1a_3a_4a_5$$
Then, we apply $(1,3)$ to our new permutation
$$(1,3)[a_2a_1a_3a_4a_5]=a_3a_1a_2a_4a_5$$
now $(1,4)$
$$(1,4)[a_3a_1a_2a_4a_5]=a_4a_1a_2a_3a_5$$
and finally $(1,5)$
$$(1,5)[a_4a_1a_2a_3a_5]= a_5a_1a_2a_3a_4$$

so $(1,2,3,4,5)=(1,5)(1,4)(1,3)(1,2)$.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, so that's what we are doing. We are showing that if we apply the left and right side on a set of 5 things, we get the same thing.

Comment: @TheMathNoob yes, we get the same permutation over the set $n$ consisting of $n$ elements.

Answer (score 3):

This is what happens (each arrow represents a separate transposition, applied right-to-left):

$a_1\to a_2\to a_2\to a_2\to a_2\\
a_2\to a_1 \to a_3\to a_3\to a_3\\
a_3\to a_3\to a_1\to a_4\to a_4\\
a_4\to a_4\to a_4\to a_1\to a_5\\
a_5\to a_5\to a_5\to a_5\to a_1.$

For example, in the third "row" $(a_1\ a_2)$ fixes $a_3$ (doesn't affect it), so we pass it unchanged to $(a_1\ a_3)$. This interchanges $a_3$ with $a_1$, and $a_1$ is interchanged by $(a_1\ a_4)$ with $a_4$, which is then unaffected by $(a_1\ a_5)$.

Writing these as functions we have (for example), again focusing on "row three":

$((a_1\ a_5)\circ(a_1\ a_4)\circ(a_1\ a_3)\circ(a_1\ a_2))(a_3)=$

$(a_1\ a_5)[(a_1\ a_4)((a_1\ a_3)((a_1\ a_2)(a_3)))]=$

$(a_1\ a_5)[(a_1\ a_4)((a_1\ a_3)(a_3))]=$

$(a_1\ a_5)[(a_1\ a_4)(a_1)]=$

$(a_1\ a_5)(a_4) = a_4$, that is, our composition sends $a_3 \to a_4$.

(I admit it's a bit awkward to have "function names" that directly reference domain elements).

So we see that overall $a_1 \to a_2 \to a_3 \to a_4 \to a_5 \to a_1$, which is exactly what the $5$-cycle $(a_1\ a_2\ a_3\ a_4\ a_5)$ does.